# (in-)compatible gradings of an associative algebra tell us...?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

If an associative algebra `A` is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded, then it is automatically $\mathbb{Z}\_2$ (aka $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$) graded by defining $A\_{\bar{0}}$ to be the direct sum over the even graded elements of `A`, and $A\_{\bar{1}}$ to be the direct sum over the odds.  Conversely, what may be said to distinguish those algebras `A` for which a $\mathbb{Z}\_2$-grading exists, but no compatible $\mathbb{Z}$-grading exists?  (Of course, compatible in the sense that the induced grading just described matches the given one.)

My motivation is the study of the `B(0,n)` (aka `osp(1|2n)`) series of Lie superalgebras, which I have been told cannot be $\mathbb{Z}$-graded, thus making their study a bit different from several of the other classes of Lie superalgebras.

The question can also be generalized greatly from above, and I think this is the right generalization.  Say $\pi:R\to S$ is a surjection of abelian groups, so that an associative algebra `A` graded over `R` is automatically graded over `S`.  What properties does an algebra have if it has an `S` grading, but no compatible `R` grading?

For a boring example, the associative algebra $\mathbb{Z}\_2$ (with itself as base field) is graded over itself as an abelian group, but clearly cannot be $\mathbb{Z}$-graded.  In fact, any finite associative algebra with nontrivial grading over $\mathbb{Z}\_2$ cannot be given a compatible $\mathbb{Z}$ grading.

Comment: I can't seem to get that first line to render correctly.

Comment: Fixed that for you. (A rare un-ironic use of that phrase. :) ) This is a well known bug with the underscore character. The temporary workaround is to write (backslash)(underscore) whenever you mean (underscore).

Comment: The last statement of the post (In fact, any finite associative algebra with nontrivial grading over Z_2 cannot be given a compatible Z grading.) is clearly wrong for the Grassmann algebra? You should be a bit more careful here.

Comment: Finite, not finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

A $\mathbb{Z}/2$ grading on a ring is equivalent to an action of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on the ring: act by $(-1)$ on the odd part. Hence, it gives a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ action on the underlying variety. Similarly, a $\mathbb{Z}$ grading gives an action of $\mathbb{C}^\*$: the element $g \in \mathbb{C}^\*$ acts on $A\_i$ by $g^i$.

So, the question is when a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ action extends to an action of $\mathbb{C}^*$. In that generality, I can't think of anything intelligent to say beyond what I've said.